Chrome Command Line option --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false working in unexpected way
I have created a process in .NET Core and opening a chrome browser with arguments " --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false --remote-debugging-port=0". I have connected to the websocket through Postman. I have used "Page.navigate" CDP for opening a URL in chrome tab.
When ever I used the above arguments, when a URL is passed to "Page.navigate" it is not loading Ajax/Fetch requests and when I remove the " --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false" chrome is sending Ajax/Fetch requests.
Is this expected behavior?
Or are there any chrome command line options which will allow Ajax/Fetch requests when
" --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false" is used ass arguments?

Sounds like a bug. Try quoting the value --blink-settings="imagesEnabled=false".

Still same issue after quoting also
